# i3-msg how to execute a specific command right after termite startup

Tags: bash, command-line, i3, termite

I'm using this command to start my i3 layout:
`exec --no-startup-id "i3-msg 'workspace 1; append_layout /home/michael/.i3/workspace-1.json'; exec termite; exec termite"`

I have two windows which swallow these `termite` instances. I'd love to have `htop` and `ranger` executed right after each terminal starts. Unfortunately `exec htop` i.e. right after `...; exec termite;...` is not working even using `&&` is not working.

I thought about having starting this via `~/.bashrc` but how to have two separate commands run for each terminal instance? Is there a way to label a command and ask for that label within `bashrc` ?

Answer (score 2):

I figure out `termite` has a `-e` option where you can append a shell command onto.

`exec termite -e ranger` is what I wanted to achieve.